# Printing Data Separate Lines Using Beautiful Soup Module

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am getting data from fortune 500 company website (http://fortune.com/fortune500/list/). Im trying to display the rows exactly how you see them on the web page.

I have tried looping through the "ul" class and it all prints in one line instead of seperate rows.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sauce = 
urllib.request.urlopen("http://fortune.com/fortune500/list/").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html.parser')


for company in soup.findAll("ul", {"class": "company-list"}):
    print(company.text)
```

expected results:

```
Rank    Company                   revenues($M)
 1        Walmart                    $500,343
 2         Exxon                     $244,363
 etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

from your code taking `company` as `variable`

```
import pandas as pd
data = company.get_text("|").split("|") 
rank =data[0::3][1:-1] ## not taking last line 
company = data[1::3][1:]
revenue = data[2::3][1:]
df = pd.DataFrame({"rank":rank,"company":company,"revenue":revenue})
```

`print(df.head())`

```
ix  rank    company revenue
0   1   Walmart $500,343
1   2   Exxon Mobil $244,363
2   3   Berkshire Hathaway  $242,137
3   4   Apple   $229,234
4   5   UnitedHealth Group  $201,159
```